# How to join two collection in mongo by using lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of **orders** and **users**. I need to filter order collection by using mongo query.Here i have a collection of users something like below

```
[
 {
  _id:1,
  order:[
   {
     orderId:2,
     shopId:8
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Collection of orders is like below

```
 [ {
      _id:1,
      shop:[
       {
         shopId:9
       },
       {
         shopId:3
       }
      ]
     }
     {
      _id:2,
      shop:[
       {
         shopId:8
       },
       {
         shopId:4
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
```

I only have a user id which is **1** and i need to query to the order and filter project on the basis of user array of object where **orderId** is and **2** and it should have **shopId** which is **8**  And it should only return those shop of project which have shopId is 6

Expected output will be like that,

```
[
      {
          _id:2,
          shop:[
           {
             shopId:8
           }
          ]
      }
]
```

Comment: Please post sample output JSON how you want.

Comment: Please check, i have added @MayuriSKulkarni

Comment: Okay, how have you tried doing that?

Comment: I was doing by using javascript filter do we have any way to do this in a mongo query

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
    {$lookup:
        {
         from: "users",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "order.orderId" ,
         as: "users"
        }
    }
    ,{$unwind : "$users" }
    ,{$project : 
        { "_id": "$_id",
          "shop": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$shop",
                as: "s",
                cond: {$in: ["$$s.shopId", "$users.order.shopId"]} } }
        }}
 ] )
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "shop" : [ 
        {
            "shopId" : 8.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ShopId is not hardcoded in my case I need to match the data which we have in user collection

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change static value :) Answer fixed.

Comment: I have some other fields too, i need to query to the order table instead users